# Unable to encrypt my Note 5 anymore (data partition is corrupt)

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, encryption, samsung-galaxy-note-5

It all started with a factory reset on the stock Samsung ROM (Android 7.0).
After I booted into the factory reset system I couldn't get the phone encryption to work: it failed with the message saying that the data partition is corrupt which effectively factory reset my phone again (forcefully).

- Reflashing the official Samsung ROM didn't help, the phone kept showing me the same message about the corruption of the data partition.
- Reformatting the partition in the TWRP didn't help either.

Any ideas how to fix it? It could also be a hardware failure.

I posted the same question on XDA but unfortunately got no response so far.

Comment: @alecxs what would I get from knowing if the problem is related to EFS or DATA?

Comment: idea behind was to figure out if problem just related to encryption and not wear-out of userdata partition itself, 
and see if you still may use device unencrypted. but turns out the encryption key is located at end of userdata partition and not EFS (forceencrypt=footer;length=-20480)

Comment: @alecxs the device is perfectly usable without encryption. Could it be wear-out after 3.5 years of usage?

Comment: if it is perfectly usable then it's most likely not wear-out. maybe it runs out of memory during encryption, or too much data on it (even after reset?)

Comment: I don't know why this shoud make a difference, but some people recommend to perform factory reset from stock android system recovery (instead twrp)

Comment: @alecxs how it is possible that there is too much data after a reset? The first reset I did was made even from the system, not from TWRP.

Comment: you ask for ideas. idk when exactly encryption starts but all the /system apps (and carrier bloat /preload apps) are extracted into /data on first boot. you could try to reduce apps, or manually wipe other partitions (EFS?) like stock recovery does

Comment: did you reflash official Samsung ROM from Odin/completely stock (even stock boot/recovery)?

Comment: @alexcs I flashed with heimdall since there is no Odin build for GNU/Linux. I believe I flashed everything except the stock recovery.

Comment: so in order to get successfully booted with custom recovery you probably disabled dm-verity? on the other hand in forum some people reported encryption won't work after flashing dm-verity disabler, so give complete stock a try

Comment: @alexcx I don't remember disabling it and I also don't remember the exact order of my actions but I think I first did a factory reset from the system and after that installed TWRP. So you believe I should try flashing all the stock images?

Comment: @alexcs after flashing all the stock .bin's the phone encrypted itself without any problems. Thank you so much for the help. Do you think I can bring back the TWRP now? Also, I can't upvote your comments for some reason.

Comment: @alecxs I flashed TWRP through heimdall (as recovery, not boot) and it worked, BUT the system became unbootable (probably because of dm-verity that detected  the change to recovery) and TWRP couldn't mount the encrypted internal storage. By flashing the stock recovery image I got the system to work again. I think I could live without a custom recovery but I want to root my phone again. Flashing a Magisk patched boot.img made the system unbootable again. Anything else I can do here?

Comment: @alecxs TWRP 3.2.3 still shows /sdcard as an empty partition. Tried 3.2.2 - no luck.

Comment: open issue on [github](https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_samsung_noblelte)

Comment: @alexcs I considered moving to Lineage OS. In fact, I even like it more than the stock Samsung bloatware. But I am worried because it's an unofficial build.

Comment: @alecxs just flashed https://forum.xda-developers.com/note5/orig-development/rom-lineageos-15-1-note-5-android-8-1-t3737405 and even with this ROM I have troubles encrypting the phone. It just goes into boot loop after I enable encryption.

Comment: try combination of LineageOS and stock recovery (+ factory reset from stock recovery) and try older (stable) LineageOS 14 based on Android 7

Comment: it seems that Magisk Manager has a bug since v7.3.5 as workaround you must "keep force encryption" and flash no-verity-opt-encrypt instead https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flashing complete stock ROM including stock recovery will fix encryption, if you factory reset from stock recovery.

To make your ROM boot along with TWRP you need to flash `no-verity-opt-encrypt` or `universal disable dm-verity`.

Due some bug in TWRP, decryption dialog fails to open because EFS is not mounted at the time that TWRP checks for device encryption. TWRP is working along with stock ROM encryption if you swap entries in `/etc/recovery.fstab` and one of these flags for USERDATA:

```
flags=encryptable=footer
flags=encryptable=footer,length=-16384
flags=encryptable=footer,length=-20480
flags=encryptable=/efs/metadata
flags=encryptable=/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/metadata
flags=encryptable=/dev/block/platform/15570000.ufs/by-name/EFS/metadata
flags=fileencryption=aes-256-xts:aes-256-cts
flags=fileencryption=ice:aes-256-cts
flags=fileencryption=ice:aes-256-cts;keydirectory=/metadata/vold/metadata_encryption
```

source: [source.android.com/security/encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based#enabling-file-based-encryption)

Comment: @alexcs Unfortunately, none of those flags worked. Tried with both TWRP 3.2.3 and TWRP 3.3.1